# Why getting very different results in each iteration of cross validation?

Tags: neural-networks, python, cross-validation

I am using 5 fold cross validation on my data. X_train is an array with shape (1303, 320, 320, 1) and y_train is an array of binary values with length 1303. I am using the below code to perform cross validation and train my ResNet50 network:

```
k = 5
fold_indices = kfold_indices(X_train, k)

model = ResNet50()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', 'AUC'])

for train_indices, val_indices in fold_indices:

    X_train_fold, y_train_fold = X_train[train_indices], y_train[train_indices]
    X_val, y_val = X_train[val_indices], y_train[val_indices]

    train_res = model.fit(X_train_fold, y_train_fold, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_val, y_val),validation_batch_size=32, verbose=1, callbacks=[temp_logger])
```

I am getting different results for train and validation in each iteration of cross validation, as:

```
train mean AUC in each iteration:
0.7292827916145325 0.9911921155452729 0.9974953067302704 0.9980593228340149 0.9993876588344573
-------------------------------------------
validation mean AUC in each iteration:
0.5288310813903808 0.7533132016658783 0.8247280997037888 0.8293656277656555 0.9171728444099426
```

and

```
train mean accuracy in each iteration:
0.6914093923568726 0.9705464994907379 0.9879194617271423 0.9896836042404175 0.9960306787490845
-------------------------------------------
validation mean accuracy in each iteration:
0.5172307753562927 0.6930000007152557 0.7857692342996597 0.7898461532592773 0.8876922965049744
```

I am not sure if this is normal, or there is something wrong with my implementation.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example? Your code above currently shows now imports or function/class definitions to assure us what you are using.

Comment: @Galen Thanks. What kind of example can I provide?

Comment: [MRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example).